# ASP.NET MVC model binding - different names for JSON property and C# model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I've annotated the properties of my model classes as below.

```
[DataMember(Name = "EN")]
public string EmployeeName{ get; set; }
```

This overall results in a compact JSON (I'm serializing using JSON.NET serializer).

However when JSON containing these smaller names is passed using a POST or a PUT request to the controllers, ASP.NET MVC model binding is not able to correctly map the "EN" JSON property to `EmployeeName`. It expects `EmployeeName` in JSON.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that out-of-the box. You have two ways of solving this: either renaming properties in your viewmodel (after all, it is a *view* model, so it has to cope with your restrictions) or you can try writing your own `ModelBinder` which will take `DataMember` annotations into consideration when binding properties.